# PHP - Infinity loop with pcntl_fork

Tags: php, loops, pcntl

I need to write code which meets few conditions:

- Is an infinity loop
- After 4 forks, goes to sleep for 5 seconds.
- When in child process, execute things.
- When in parent process, fork again.
- When it returns -1, catch exception.

So here's what I've written so far:

```
while(true) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; ++$i) {
        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if($pid == 0){
            //execute stuff
        } else if ($pid == -1){
            //error
        } else if($pid > 0) {
            //fork again?
        }
    }
    sleep(5);
}
```

But I feel like this is just plain wrong. Also I have no idea how to fork again in parent. How this should look like?

Comment: Is this for learning purposes or do you have a real problem you're solving? Also, after you fork 4 times and go to sleep(5), is the code supposed to fork 4 times again or just once?

Comment: What you've got there is a fork bomb - every child process will also fork.

Comment: @Mjh Learning purposes. My friend just gave me conditions my code should meet. It is supposed to go 4 times again. And again. Untill the end of time, or server goes down :P

Comment: Since you are in `while(true)`, after sleeping for 5 seconds you'll fork again (that's what your parent process is doing).

Comment: Start by reading up on `pcntl_fork` http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php